# javascript - modifying text entered into TextBox

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I would like to catch an event that some text was entered to a TextBox and modify it BEFORE user sees the change.
I tried adding the keyDown, keyUp and keyPressed events, but they are all called after the change.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `BEFORE user sees the change` - who is entering this text, not user?

Comment: You mean change it few seconds after the input changes?

Comment: Yes - but i want, for example, to delete specific characters if user tries to insert them

Comment: Ivan - no, i want to modify the change before user sees it on screen

Comment: Is it gwt or pure JavaScript?

Comment: @Erik Do you mean to restrict the user by entering specific characters only

Answer (score 0):

This has to work

```
  $("#input").keypress(function(replace){ 
        if(replace.which==46)
        {
            $("#input").val($(this).val() + 'no_dots');
            replace.preventDefault();
        }
  });
```

It replaces (,) characters, try this code I think it `keypress` works well

Comment: keypress is called after the change tool place - the user already sees the changed text

Comment: Maybe you should execute your functions before `replace.preventDefault()`? just a suggestion.

Comment: check this one `http://jsfiddle.net/cDE3L/4/`, I think it is based on what I understood. I can't go any further. good luck

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're after. http://jsfiddle.net/wcS9j/1/

```
var blacklist = /(foo|bar)/ig;

$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    if (blacklist.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(blacklist, '');
    }
});
```